# Javascript DOM manipulation Technique on Facebook Group

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom, appendchild, createelement

I am looking for an easy way to implement DOM manipulation to a Facebook Group page. Here is  a facebook group members list:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/39926005765/members/
As you can see, there is a link 'See More' at the bottom of the members list. We have to click this link again and again to display all members.  Is there any way using Javascript DOM technique to list all members with a single click.  I am trying to create a simple bookmarklet or something to do this.  Instead of click 10 times, a single click to list all members. Is there an easy way to do this? Highly appreciate your inputs.

Ishaq.

Comment: When writing to SO, you should provide what have you tried so far so other users can help you, but do not ask for code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are the admin of this group you can access for this data using the graph api without problem.

Applications can get the list of members that belong to a group by issuing a GET request to /GROUP_ID/members with an app access_token.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I am trying to do this without using Graph API.  Here is a sample code of my Bookmarklet app.                            javascript:h=document.documentElement.innerHTML;hC=h.replace(/\n/g,' ');hC=hC.replace(/\r/g,' ');alert(hC);  I can see the HTML code of Facebook members page, but don't know how to manipulate with the 'See More' link given at the bottom of members link.

Comment: without using the graph api it´s not allowed, that would be scraping

Answer (score 0):

if you obtain the url in the link and send via js this request using ajax obtain the next persons without press the bottom , the problem is when you press the buttom have one function that add more var for this request for security etc token, you need look in the facebook function to check what they add for this call.

```
var httpRequest;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}  
httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://www.facebook.com/ajax/browser/list/group_members/?id=39926005765&gid=39926005765&edge=groups%3Amembers&order=default&view=grid&start=192&__user=628443668&__a=1&__dyn=7n8apij35CFUlgDxqiyaUVCxSq78hAKGgSGG&__req=o&__rev=1086465', true);
```

httpRequest.response;

Comment: This is the URL found in the 'See More' hypertext:  https://www.facebook.com/ajax/browser/list/group_members/?id=39926005765&gid=39926005765&edge=groups%3Amembers&order=default&view=grid&start=96                   When we click this link Each time, the value start=96 is getting updated and everything else is same.